# how to bind gridview to sqldatasource to our own created form

Tags: asp.net

I have a form and 'Add' button. when i click on add then i insert data into database and also i have sqldatasource in which i specify only select,update,delete commands. when i insert data on Add button then i want to refresh and fill the grid automatically.
my sqldatasource id is "sqldatasourceDenter" and i have specified it in my gridview datasourceID="sqldatasourceDenter".

i have tried this 
GridView1.DataSourceID = sqldatasourceDenter;
it gives me the error cannot convert sqldatasource to string
i have also defined datasource but it tells both me both datasource, datasourceID cannot be defined.

I actually want to insert data on my 'Add' button then refresh the sqldataSourceDenter to fill the grid.

---

This is my add button click event function:

```
..... add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
..
.... /* here i have other code*/
.....
        else {

            string dentername = dname.Text.ToString();

            string denteraddress = daddress.Text.ToString();
            string dentercontact = dcontact.Text.ToString();

            //create sql inset query and take to insert query ftn for execution
            string dquery = string.Format("INSERT INTO Denters(D_NIC, D_Name, D_Address, D_Contact) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", denternic, dentername, denteraddress, dentercontact);

            InsertIntoDB.InsertQuery(dquery);
            if (InsertIntoDB.count > 0)
            {

                gvDenter.DataSourceID = SqlDataSourceDenter;
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Denter added successfully')</script>");
                InsertIntoDB.count = 0;
                ClearDenterFields();
            }
        }
}
```

My aspx code is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDenter" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VehiclesSystemConnectionString2 %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT [D_NIC], [D_Name], [D_Address], [D_Contact] FROM [Denters]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="gvDenter" Visible="False" DataKeyNames="D_NIC" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDenter" >
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDataToGrid();
    }
}

protected void BindDataToGrid()
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery);
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Insert To DB Code here
}
```